# Cómo controlar cómo inicia un checkbox con JS

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo mi conjunto de `checkbox` el cual siempre inicia en `checked=true`. Yo quiero que el estado del `checked` dependa de un valor que le mande por js ya que este valor lo traigo desde la base de datos. Tengo una lista de 10 `checkbox` que guardé en la base de datos, quiero que estos coincidan con los valores que tengo guardados pero no sé cómo hacer que unos estén marcados o desmarcados dependiendo de ese valor. Quiero que si el valor que recibo sea un 0, el `checkbox` esté desmarcado, de igual forma, si recibo un 1, esté marcado.

```
<div class="custom-switch custom-switch-label-yesno">
<input class="custom-switch-input" id="limpieza_chk" type="checkbox" checked="">
<label class="custom-switch-btn" for="limpieza_chk"></label>
<input id="limpieza_val" type="hidden" value="1">
<input id="limpieza_comments" type="hidden">
</div>
```

Comment: Creo que para dar una respuesta es necesario saber la estructura del "js" (arreglo, objeto, o json)  con el que pretendes gestionar los checkbox

Comment: `if ( valorEnLaDBesTrue ) { elInput.setAttribute( "checked", "checked" ) } else { elInput.removeAttribute("checked") }`

Comment: Me sirvió lo que comentaste alo, muchas gracias

Comment: No olvides colocarlo como respuesta y explicarlo @aloMalbarez, para que el OP pueda [aceptarla](/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 1):

En principio obtenemos todos los elementos con **querySelectorAll** mediante la clase *custom-switch-input*, se supone que ya deberían tener un valué asignado desde la bd, dependiendo si es **1 o 0** el atributo *check* sera asignado o removido, ejemplo:

```js
//OBTENEMOS LOS ELEMENTOS MEDIANTE LA CLASE, CON QUERYSELECTORALL YA NOS GENERA UN ARRAY ITERABLE
var checks = document.querySelectorAll('.custom-switch-input');

//RECORREMOS EL ARRAY DE ELEMENTOS
checks.forEach(elem => {
  //VERIFICAMOS EL VALUE DE CADA ELEMENTO, SI ES 1 SE MARCA
  if (elem.value == 1) {
    elem.setAttribute("checked", "checked");
    //console.log(elem);
  } else { //SI ES 0 REMOVEMOS EL ATRIBUTO
    elem.removeAttribute("checked");
  }
});
```

```html
<input class="custom-switch-input" id="1" type="checkbox" value="1"> check 1
<input class="custom-switch-input" id="2" type="checkbox" value="0"> check 2
<input class="custom-switch-input" id="3" type="checkbox" value="0"> check 3
<input class="custom-switch-input" id="4" type="checkbox" value="1"> check 4
<input class="custom-switch-input" id="5" type="checkbox" value="1"> check 5
```

Dime si te sirbio.